# xpath match only if grandparent matches a specific name

Tags: xpath

I have the following structure in which I want to get a list of all nodes with a name of `innerItem`.  The only node name i can use in the query is `childId` for external reasons.

The complexity is that the childId node is found in both the `innerItem` node and the innerItemData node.

I must only match innerItem` as i want to return all of these.

Is this possible with a single xpath expression?

Essentially i want to say, find me all innerItem nodes that have a childId node with a value of 123 and a grandParent node name of "Container".

I need to work off of the grandparent as this will never change and will always be called "Container" whereas innerContainer_abc can change i.e. it can be innerContainer_def etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Container>
    <MetaData>
        <id>1</id>
        <date />
    </MetaData>
    <innerContainer_abc>
        <innerItem>
            <childId>123</childId>
            <childCode>123-abc</childCode>
            <innerItemData>
                <childId>123</childId>
            </innerItemData>
        </innerItem>
        <innerItem>
            <childId>123</childId>
            <childCode>123-def</childCode>
            <innerItemData>
                <childId>123</childId>
            </innerItemData>
        </innerItem>
    </innerContainer_abc>
<Container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for:

```
//Container/*/innerItem[childId='123']
```

This is looking for all innerItem with element childId wiht value "123" as direct child and 
Container as "grandparent".